# Linux 2.6.39.4 how to find available loadable kernel modules

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I'm customizing the 2.6.39.4 linux kernel on an arm platform and trying to test out a ["Hello World"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c147.htm) driver I created. I selected "M" (loadable) in the kernel make menuconfig and verified that it showed up in the .config and that the hello.o was created during compilation of the kernel.

When I start the Kernel with the above linux image loaded, I try doing a find / -name *.ko
and find / -name *.o to see where my loadable hello world module is located - but I come up with nothing aside from a few other lkms.

Anyone know if there's a command I'm missing that lists all available lkms?

Comment: Did you do `make modules_install` as well? The modules are under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize I had to do a make modules and then make modules_install...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such modules are normally created out-of-tree, and loaded from there. Besides, the module objects have extension `.ko`, if the name isn't right, the module won't be loaded. E.g. the example "Hello, world!" module from [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3) still builds and works fine (Fedora 20 on x86_64).

Comment: Ok, so after I create my uImage, I can just run make modules to create the modules(.ko) files, but then I assume I'll have to include them in the filesystem and not the uImage?